# Access Django devserver from another machine same network

Tags: python, linux, django, fedora

I'm using django's builtin server to develop a site and I want other computers in the same network I'm on to be able to access the server using the local IP address.
I have seen many posts about this and after trying all suggestions it's still not allowing other computers in my network to access the site.

I run the server using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and have already opened port `8000` as you can see in the following image.

[image]

I'm running Django 1.4.2, Python 2.7.3, Fedora 18 on kernel 3.8.11-200

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Use `python manage.py runserver <ip>:<port>`

For example,my IP is 192.168.0.100 and I want to run django app on port 80,I have to do

```
[sudo] python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.100:80
```

My port 80 needed root permissions,maybe because I have other applications accessing it.

You also have to add the IP address to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list in settings.py

By doing this all clients in the 192.168.0 network will be able to access the site at 192.168.0.100

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. But this would not work as my local Apache is using port 80 and port 8000 is the one most django devs use therefore I didn't want to go for anything new. Also the 0.0.0.0:8000 indicate any ip on port 8000 so it would not make much difference to give it a specific one.

Answer (score 4):

You're starting Django as needed - it will accept connections from anywhere as soon as the connections get to it.

Check your firewall and make sure it's allowing 8000 port connections. Something like this should work:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

Optionally you will need to extend the `INTERNAL_IPS` variable in the setting to allow remote debugging: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#internal-ips .

Answer (score 4):

skarap is correct.  If your network is configured correctly and your django application with pytho9n manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 and you still can't access your django app from the VM host there is almost certainly a firewall issue.  The illustration above is good if you are running iptables.

I deployed CentOS 7 on a virtualbox VM from a Windows 7 host.  I didn't know that this distribution uses firewalld, not iptables to control access.

if

> ps -ae | grep firewall
>   returns something like
>    602 ?            00:00:00 firewalld

your system is running firewalld, not iptables.  They do not run together.

To correct you VM so you can access your django site from the host use the commands:

> firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent
>   firewall-cmd --reload

Many thanks to pablo v on the http://www.scriptscoop.net site for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the server IP to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in the settings.py

Answer (score 0):

set  firewall rules with
$ sudo ufw enable
$ sudo ufw allow 8000

type ipconfig
copy addr under inet

do python3 manage.py runserver your_inet_addr:8000